# this doesn't act the same in lambda and without it in ecma6 javascript and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda, ecmascript-6

```
var emitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var util = require('util');

let Person = function (name) {
    this.name = name;

};

util.inherits(Person, emitter);
let p = new Person("jonny");

p.on('speak', (said) => {
    console.log(` ${this.name} said: ${said}`);

});

p.emit('speak', "You may delay but time will not!");
```

console will return

> undefined said: You may delay but time will not!

if you change from lambda back

```
p.on('speak', function(said) {
    console.log(` ${this.name} said: ${said}`);

});
```

it works. can some explain to me why this acts differently with syntactic sugar changes?

Comment: Because is not only sugar. `=>` doesn't create new context and hasn't `this`.

Comment: The `function()` version is also a lambda.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/186/functions/720/arrow-functions#t=201608012207550133428

Comment: @MichkeyPerlstein : I update my answer & i [suggest a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38708833/747579)

Comment: Either use `p.name` or use a normal function. Arrow functions don't work the way you want them to.

Comment: Also a duplicate of [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/218196)

Answer (score 0):

Arrow function (Lambda) has not neither `this` nor `arguments`. And if you find `this` or `arguments` , it belongs to its function caller .

Therefore  , you need to use classic function until upgrading [`events` package](http://npmjs.com/package/events) & supporting this feature .

## Update:

IF you love arrow function  & you insist to use it , i suggest to override `on` method AND convert arrow function to classic-function using `eval`

```
class Person extends require('events').EventEmitter{

     constructor(name){
      super();
       this.name=name;
     }
     on(event,arrow){
         super.on.call(this,event,eval(`(function${arrow.toString().replace('=>','')})`));
     }
}

let p = new Person("jonny");

p.on('speak', (said) => {
    console.log(` ${this.name} said: ${said}`);

});

p.emit('speak', "You may delay but time will not!");
```

## DEMO :

[image]

Comment: Please don't recommend `eval`, that's not at all a general answer. If that function depended on anything besides `this` and `said`, it would break immediately.

Comment: i knew,,, hust for his requirements

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI thanks for your answer, but I did not require anything. I asked why javascript is behaving in a way that I do not understand. I come from C#, where "arrow functions" do not act in this manner and are in fact syntactic sugar.